# Do finite components get smaller as supercritical random graphs with an arbitrary degree sequence get denser?

Tags: random-graphs, percolation, complex-networks

I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745380/average-finite-component-sizes-of-random-graph-under-stochastic-dominance) question a few weeks ago on MSE but did not receive any responses so I am going to ask a related but more specific question here.

First some notation.
Let $\mathbb{G} = \mathbb{G}(n,\mathbf{d})$ be a simple random graph on $n$ vertices chosen uniformly at random (e.g. constructed by the configuration model). Let $\mathcal{D}_0 = \{p_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ denote the limiting degree distribution which we assume satisfies standard regularity conditions. I'm also going to assume that the graph is sufficiently sparse that we can approximate it locally by a branching process.

In the title of my question I ask about what happens when supercritical graphs (i.e. graphs which have a giant component whp as $n\to\infty$) "get denser". I mostly care about changes in the component sizes under different kinds of percolation, which are directly related to how dense the graph is, though it would of course be nice to know what happens under, for example, any first-order stochastic dominant shift in the degree distribution. To keep things as clean as possible I'm only going to ask about the simplest form of site percolation.

Suppose we perform site percolation on the random graph $\mathbb{G}$– i.e. we randomly delete each vertex (independently) and all edges incident with it with probability $1-q$. Call the resulting graph $\mathbb{G}_q \subseteq \mathbb{G}_1 = \mathbb{G}$. Let $c_i(\mathbb{G})$ be the probability that a randomly chosen vertex in $\mathbb{G}$ is in a component of size $i \in \mathbb{N}$ (as $n\to\infty$). Suppose $\mathbb{G}$ is supercritical and let $q_c$ be the percolation threshold so that $\mathbb{G}_q$ is supercritical if $q>q_c$ and subcritical if $q<q_c$. It's relatively easy to show (via a branching process approach) that if $q < q_c,$ then the expectation of the distribution $\{c_i(\mathbb{G}_q)\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is increasing in $q$.

**My question is then:** is the expectation of $\{c_i(\mathbb{G}_q)\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ decreasing in $q$ for all $q>q_c$?

**Some notes on the problem:**

We know that when we move just past the critical threshold $q_c,$ the distribution over finite component sizes must be decreasing since it diverges to infinity at $q_c$ and is finite everywhere else. In fact one can show this rigorously by using a Taylor expansion for some relevant generating function around $1$ (which is the extinction probability when $q<q_c$). But what happens when we move away from the critical threshold? Intuitively, the giant component starts to "swallow up" vertices which were in large finite components, so the only components that survive are very small ones. This is why I *think* the component sizes are decreasing. In fact, it might even be true that the distribution over component sizes can be ordered by first-order stochastic dominance as a function of $q$.

Here's my attempt at a solution using generating functions and branching processes (somewhat heuristically, but this can be made rigorous). The argument below follows Callaway et al. (2000). Let $G_{0}(x)$ be the generating function for the limiting degree distribution $\mathcal{D}_0$. Let $\mathcal{D}_1$ denote the size-biased (or *excess*) degree distribution, and $G_1(x) = \frac{G_0(x)}{G_0^\prime(1)}$ its generating function.

Now for the percolation. Consider choosing a vertex $i$ at random from $\mathbb{G}$ and following each edge incident with $i$ to one of $i$'s neighbor. Each of $i$'s neighbors in $\mathbb{G}$ are also in $\mathbb{G}_q$ with (independent) probability $q,$ else they are deleted (i.e. have degree $0$) with probability $1-q$. It follows that the generating function for the size-biased degree distribution in $\mathbb{G}_q$ is
$$
G_1(1-q+qx).
$$
So the extinction probability of a branching process exploration in $\mathbb{G}_q$ is the smallest solution in $[0,1]$ to
$$
\eta = G_1(1-q+q\eta).
$$
Let $H_1(x)$ be the generating function for the probability that one end of a randomly chosen *edge* on the graph $\mathbb{G}$ leads to a component of a given number of occupied vertices in the percolated graph $\mathbb{G}_q$. Let $H_0(x)$ be the generating function for the distribution of component sizes for a randomly chosen *vertex* in $\mathbb{G}_q$. Then one can show that $H_0$ and $H_1$ have to satisfy the “self consistency” conditions
$$H_1(x) = 1-q+qzG_1[H_1(x)]\\
H_0(x) = 1-q+qzG_0[H_1(x)]
$$
It follows that the expected *forward* component size (excluding vertices which may be in the component) is
$$
H_1^\prime(1) = qG_1[H_1(1)] + q H_1^\prime(1)G_1^\prime[H_1(1)] = \frac{q\eta}{1-qG_1^\prime(1-q+q\eta)}.
$$
where the last equality from the fact that $H_1(1)=1−q +q\eta$ where $\eta$ is the extinction probability of a branching process in $\mathbb{G}_q$. Let's forget about $H_0^\prime(1)$ for a second and focus on this "forward" component size $H_1^\prime(1)$ which has a relatively simple form. It seems reasonable to think that $H_1^\prime(1)$ is also decreasing when $q>q_c$ for exactly the same reason that we might think $H_0^\prime(1)$ is decreasing when $q>q_c$. In fact, when $q<q_c$ we know $\eta(q) = 1,$ and its easy to show directly by differentiating with respect to $q$ that $H_1^\prime(1)$ is strictly increasing in $q$.

**This is where I am stuck with this approach.**  When $q>q_c,$ the derivative with respect to $q$ requires an implicit differentiation of $\eta$ with respect to $q$. Using $\eta(q) = G_1(1-q+q\eta(q))$ we can compute this derivative and show that it's negative (this is kind of obvious, as $q$ increases, the extinction probability decreases). BUT, as $q$ goes up, can we say whether $qG_1^\prime(1-q+q\eta)$ goes up or down? The question really amounts to asking whether $\eta(q)$ decreases "faster" than $q$ increases. And I am not sure whether this is true. I suspect that working out the right way to answer the question for $H_1^\prime(1)$ will also allow me to answer the question for $H_0^\prime(1)$.

I might be thinking about this the wrong way, but branching processes give a particularly tractable way of thinking about the expected component size, so it seems very natural to approach the problem in this way. I've been able to find some relevant papers in the statistical physics literature on this (e.g. by Newman), and Janson has [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1656) on percolation in random graphs with an arbitrary degree sequence, but the focus is not really on component sizes. I'm not sure if there's some clean result that I'm just unaware of, but if so, please point me to the paper!